# Php exec returns empty array on very specific command

Tags: php, linux, pulseaudio

In the following:

```
exec('sudo -u myuser pactl list sink-inputs 2>&1', $output, $err);
```

`$output` is an empty array and `$err` is `0`.

Any other command works fine, for example `sudo -u myuser pactl info` or `sudo -u myuser whoami` work just fine and return the result as an array.

***EDIT:***

When I do

`sudo -u http sudo -u myuser pactl list sink-inputs`

in order to replicate the php behavior, it gives me an error. Therefore this question doesn't belong here and is about pactl returning an error in this case.

[closed]

Comment: Maybe output contains some special characters that prevent it from being captured or displayed. Do you see the output using `passthru` function?

Comment: Have you tried running the command with the user under which the PHP script is executed?

Comment: @baf passthru doesn't return the output, just the status. How can I check whether it contains weird characters?